# Simple ajax call not working in wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, ajax

I am practice to create simple ajax wordpress plugin. I refered wordress ajax documentation and some tutorials to create plugin. How can i pass the values to get result from php file. The same code i created in normal php it works fine. How can i solve this. Here are the codes i created.

**index.php**

```
<?php
 /*
  Plugin Name: Ajax Serach
 */
  function my_assets() {

  wp_enqueue_style( 'pubmed-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'css/pubmed-style.css' );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'pubmed-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ).'js/pubmed-script.js', array('jquery'), true );

 wp_localize_script( pubmed-script, litsearch, array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

 }

  add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_assets' );
?>

 <?php
    function pubget(){
  ?>     
<input type="text" name="" value="" id="sterm"/> 
<input type="button" name="" value="Search term" id="pub_search"/>

<div id="container">olddata</div>

 <?php
 }
 add_shortcode('pubajax', 'pubget');
 ?>
```

**Test.php**

```
<?php 
class Testclass{
    function infotext(){
        $txt = 'This is a ajax response text';
    }
}
 ?>
```

**Pub.php**

```
<?php
function litsearch(){
    $newterm = $_GET['nwterm'];
    $newtest = new Testclass();
    if($newterm == $_GET['nwterm']){
        include('test.php');
        $newtest = new Testclass();
        $newtest->infotext();
    }
    die();
}
add_action('wp_ajax_litsearch', 'litsearch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_litsearch', 'litsearch');
 ?>
```

**mainjquery.js**

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
//alert("Jquery Loaded");
  jQuery("#pub_search").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked");
            event.preventDefault();           
            var term= $("#sterm").val();
            console.log('your term send: '+term);
            var data = {'nwterm': term }            
           $.get(litsearch.ajaxurl, data, function(data){
            $("#container").html(data);
          });
        });
});
```

Comment: What is the return value of the ajax call ? I assume it is -1 or 0

Comment: Are you working according to this tutorial https://pippinsplugins.com/process-ajax-requests-correctly-in-wordpress-plugins/

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the name of your wp ajax action in your data when you do the ajax call.

I assume the ajax url is correct.

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function(){
//alert("Jquery Loaded");
  jQuery("#pub_search").click(function(){
    alert("You clicked");
            event.preventDefault();           
            var term= $("#sterm").val();
            console.log('your term send: '+term);
            var data = {'nwterm': term, 'action': 'litsearch'}            
           $.get(litsearch.ajaxurl, data, function(data){
            $("#container").html(data.response);
          });
        });
});
```

Also because you want to put a response in your html code you have to send something back from server.

**Test.php**

```
<?php 
class Testclass{
    function infotext(){
        $txt = 'This is a ajax response text';
        return $txt;
    }
}
 ?>
```

**Pub.php**

```
<?php
function litsearch(){
    $newterm = $_GET['nwterm'];
    $newtest = new Testclass();
    $data = array();
    if($newterm == $_GET['nwterm']){
        include('test.php');
        $newtest = new Testclass();
        $data['response'] = $newtest->infotext();
    }
    wp_send_json( $data );
}
add_action('wp_ajax_litsearch', 'litsearch');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_litsearch', 'litsearch');
 ?>
```

Comment: console give this error Uncaught ReferenceError: litsearch is not defined. i have already created object in  wp_localize_script.

Comment: The first two variables in wp_localize_script has to be a string. You don't have quotes around the names. Also check in your html code if the js variable litsearch is there.

Comment: yes i check it's working but content not showing. it gives only zero.

Comment: According to documentation: if the request succeeds, but the Ajax action does not match a WordPress hook defined with add_action('wp_ajax_(action)', ...) or add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_(action)', ...), then admin-ajax.php will respond 0.

Comment: where i can change to get the correct result.

Comment: How pub.php is loaded?

Comment: Try to put the code of pub.php inside function.php and see if it is working

Comment: not working give this error in console wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?nwterm=bio&action=litsearch 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: You have an error in your php code. Please debug properly. Check the error.log to see what is the problem.